# Approximation in $L^2$ in a unit ball

Tags: real-analysis

We know that on an interval $I$, one can approach a $L^2 (I)$ function by a Fourier serie $\sum_{n= - \infty }^{+ \infty } a_n e^{inx}$ for all $x\in I$ (with $i^2=-1$); And so we can do it for any cube in $\mathbb R^n$.

My problem is how to make this approximation in the unit ball(Or how to find a similar approximation).
I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Cordially.

Comment: can't you do it on the cube containing the ball with the same functions?

Comment: Think you : @Exodd @ Jonas Meyer. The problem is that i need this decomposition to prove an inequaliti , this idea is not usable..

Answer (score 1):

The eigenfunctions of Laplacian in the unit ball
$$\nabla^{2}_{S^{2}\times[0, 1]}\Psi_{lmn}(\theta, \varphi, r)=-l(l+1)\Psi_{lmn}(\theta, \varphi, r)$$
with $\Psi_{lmn}(\theta, \varphi, 1)=0$, $\Psi_{lmn}(\theta+2\pi, \varphi, r)=\Psi_{lmn}(\theta, \varphi, r)$, $\Psi_{lmn}(\theta, \varphi+2\pi, r)=\Psi_{lmn}(\theta, \varphi, r)$, form an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $L^{2}(S^{2}\times[0, 1])$.
$$\Psi_{lnm}(\theta, \varphi, r)=2k_{n}j_{l}(k_{n}r)Y_{lm}(\theta, \varphi)$$
Where $j_{l}(z)$ is the $l^{th}$ order spherical bessel's function of the first kind and $Y_{lm}$s are spherical harmonics, $k_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ zero of the spherical bessel's function. Such that
$$\int_{S^{2}\times[0, 1]}\Psi^{\dagger}_{lnm}(\theta, \varphi, r)\Psi_{l'n'm'}(\theta, \varphi, r)r^{2}\sin(\theta)d\theta{d\varphi}dr=\delta_{m, m'}\delta_{l, l'}\delta_{n, n'}$$
So, that for any function $g(r, \theta, \varphi)$ on $S^{2}\times[0, 1]$ we have
$$g(r, \theta, \varphi)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}g_{lmn}\Psi_{lmn}(r, \theta, \varphi)$$
Where by inner product
$$g_{lmn}=\int_{S^{2}\times[0, 1]}g^{\dagger}(r, \theta, \varphi)\Psi(r, \theta, \varphi)r^{2}\sin(\theta)d\theta{d\varphi}dr$$

Comment: In fact, why you call this an approximation? it is absolutely exact, both Fourier series and this stuff!

Comment: Kiryl Pesotski :Think you for your help, can you give me a reference , i want to read about this method.                                                                        Here the ball is the unit ball of $\mathbb R ^3$, isnt it?

Comment: @Mokata https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1278.pdf may serve your purpose. (Note that this method is very general, it does not really have anything to do with the domain in question.)

Comment: If you want to read about it, have a look at any text on Hilbert space. Given any complete orthonormal basis of functions of some domain $D$ you can expand any function in a series of this functions (by completeness) with the coefficients given by inner product. This is a ball centered at the origin with radius 1 parameterized by spherical polar coordinates ($\theta$ is the polar angle).

Comment: The fact that you can take expansion into a complete orthonormal basis is rather obvious (it is more or less built into the word "complete"). The deeper fact is that the Dirichlet eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on a domain with smooth boundary form such a set.